# Voltage dropping capacitor doesn't drop the voltage?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, transformerless

I am going to make a transformerless power supply.

Here I am using a 105J 400V polyester capacitor to drop the voltage.

I connected the capacitor and AC main in series, but when I measure the voltage across the capacitor using a multimeter, it shows same as 220 to 230V AC and no voltage drop there.

What can I do for that? Has the capacitor gone mad?

[image]

Comment: You need to understand the principle of the series capacitor supply. Vout = Vin x Zo/(Zo+Zc) where Z0 is output impedance and Zc is capacitor impedance. Top get say 300 VDC (240V mains peak) input and say 5V output then the output impedance MUST be about 5/(300-5) x Zc. In practive a zener diode is usually used at the output to ensure a constant minimum load | Supplies of this sort **MUST** be treated as if the output is at full mains voltage. If not used with care and understanding they will kill you and your equipment.

Comment: The meter draws almost no current so you won't see a voltage drop until you apply a load. The problem with cap droppers is that if the cap breaks it supply the entire input to the load. I would avoid such PSU designs I've known such 'hacks' to burn a house down!! (I was involved in the insurance investigation)  If you want a non-isolated offline PSU, I suggest looking at some flyback modules or designs.

Comment: There are some phase angle triggered monolithic AC/DC ICs (struggling to remember the part numer) or something like the UCC3888 which uses rectified mains to PWM 400V DC down to 5V. Saying that transformerless off-line designs are rarely useful from a safety perspective if there is any external exposed conductive paths.

Answer (score 2):

The capacitor will form a voltage divider with the impedance it's feeding. If that impedance is solely that of your meter, which is very high, then the resulting voltage drop will be very small.

Once loaded with the output load, there will be a significant voltage drop.

Be warned that if your load consists of a bridge rectifier, then a reservoir capacitor, then a DC load, that the rectifier and reservoir cap must be rated for full mains voltage. If the DC load ever gets removed or fails open, then the series capacitor will no longer drop your design voltage, and the reservoir cap will charge up to full peak mains voltage, 340 V in 240 V rms land.